# Import Error with OpenAIApi in Node.js Project

Tags: chat, openai-api

I'm currently working on a Node.js project and have encountered an import error with the OpenAI API. I've recently updated to the latest version of the `openai` module. My Node.js version is v20.10.0. The error is as follows:

Error Message:
TypeError: openaiModule.default is not a constructor

Relevant Part of My Code:

```js
const openaiModule = await import('openai');
const openai = new openaiModule.default({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

I'm looking for any advice or recommended practices to resolve this import error. Is this issue related to the specific version of Node.js or the openai module? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

I am working on a chat application that uses Firebase on the client side and the latest version of the OpenAI API on the server side. It is designed to translate messages in real-time between Japanese, English, Korean, Chinese, and Russian. This setup will allow people from various countries to participate in discussions without being left out due to language barriers.
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const OpenAI = require('openai');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to the Multi-language Translation Chat App!');
});

app.post('/translate', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { message, language } = req.body;
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "text-davinci-002",
      prompt: `Translate this text to ${language}: ${message}`,
      max_tokens: 60,
    });

    res.json({ translation: response.data.choices[0].text.trim() });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error calling OpenAI:", error);
    res.status(500).send('Error processing your request');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```